# How do I click this button from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML that's generated from a server:

```
<button id="start-diag-suites" title="add new suite" tabindex="-1" class="css-wvwsyj"></button>
```

How do I click this button with Javascript?

I've tried:

```
document.getElementById('start-diag-suites').click();
```

and I've tried the slightly more complex:

````
  element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(eventName, {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    clientX: coordX,
    clientY: coordY,
    button: 0
  }));
};
var theButton = document.querySelector('#start-diag-suites');
if (theButton) {
var box = theButton.getBoundingClientRect(),
        coordX = box.left + (box.right - box.left) / 2,
        coordY = box.top + (box.bottom - box.top) / 2;
simulateMouseEvent (theButton, 'mousedown', coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (theButton, 'mouseup', coordX, coordY);
simulateMouseEvent (theButton, 'click', coordX, coordY); }```

but neither seem to work at all
````

Comment: In your second one, you did `var theButton = document.querySelector('.start-diag-suites');`, but the selector should be `#start-diag-suites`. (Also, the right answer isn’t really possible to tell from just the HTML, if that doesn’t end up working. You need to use your browser tools to inspect the event listeners on it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With jQuery:

```js
$('#start-diag-suites').click()
```

## Without jQuery:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('start-diag-suites');
button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!

Even though it's the correct answer, for some reason it still doesn't trigger the click. I can get it to work on buttons that have a classID but everything else I'm trying to click() programatically doesn't fire for some reason.